# Azure "cloud-only" Multi-Factor Authentication requires on-prem MFA Server?

Tags: azure

I am implementing a cloud-only Azure solution; we have no physical location for on-premise devices.   This is the topology of my solution:

[image: Azure Topology]

I am trying to use MFA for authenticating users with the VM over RDP (i.e., when logging into the VM over RDP, MFA is required).

However, I have not been able to get this to work.  I believe MFA (with text message) is configured correctly, and I have enabled MFA for the AD users.

I have consulted with Azure Tech Support.  They have now told me that this "cloud-only" scenario is not supported, and use of the on-premises MFA Server is required.   However, nowhere in the Azure documentation (["Getting started with Azure Multi-Factor Authentication in the cloud"](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/multi-factor-authentication-get-started-cloud/)) can I find this requirement for the MFA Server.

Has anyone successfully implemented this pure "cloud-only" solution?  Or does this scenario indeed require the on-prem MFA Server?

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/multi-factor-authentication-get-started/) you can't use Cloud MFA for remote access (VPN, RDP).